# MaxClients exceeds ServerLimit value...see the ServerLimit directive

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I want to set my serverLimit to 1024, and I am using prefork.c

So, went to prefork.c, made the change, did make, make install.

Then I did an apachectl stop && apachectl start

Not I change the directive again in httpd.conf but I'm still getting the following error:

MaxClients of 1024 exceeds ServerLimit value of 256 servers,
 lowering MaxClients to 256.  To increase, please see the ServerLimit
 directive.
Syntax OK

Any idea whatsoever I need to do?

Thanks..

Answer (score 11):

In Apache 2.x you don't need to modify source code for increasing maximum clients above 255 like in Apache 1.3 you had to.

Instead just tune your httpd.conf. Put there in prefork configuration section

```
ServerLimit 1024
MaxClients 1024
```

And you should be all set.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.  It was an order problem, ie serverlimit needs to come BEFORE MaxClients...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that in your configuration file, you don't set the ServerLimit to 256 ?

Don't forget to restart httpd so that the ServerLimit is indeed correctly changed.

You may also use the module status to get an idea of the configuration results.